# Как исправить ошибку пишет, что 'Встречено else, а ожидалось ;'?

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Помогите, пожалуйста, пишет, что 'Встречено else, а ожидалось ;'

```
Program GO;
var
a,b: integer;
w: string;
begin
  repeat
    writeln('Введите x');
    readln(a);
    writeln('Введите y');
    readln(b);
    if a or b=0 then 
      break
      else
          if ((a+b) mod 2)=0 then
        begin    
          writeln('Черная клетка')
          else {Тут ошибка}
            writeln('Белая клетка')
        end;
      else
        writeln('Ошибка');
  until a=0;
end.
```

Comment: Потому что у вас на 2 блока if 3 раза else - один лишний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в программе несколько ошибок с расстановкой операторов и терминирующих точек с запятой. Вот рабочий вариант:

```pascal
PROGRAM Go;

VAR
    a, b: Integer;

BEGIN
    WHILE TRUE DO
    BEGIN
        WriteLn('Введите x');
        ReadLn(a);

        WriteLn('Введите y');
        ReadLn(b);

        IF (a = 0) OR (b = 0) THEN BREAK;

        IF ((a + b) MOD 2) = 0 THEN
            WriteLn('Черная клетка')
        ELSE
            WriteLn('Белая клетка');
    END;
END.
```

Обратите внимание на расстановку точек с запятыми.